# Controlling evaluation in a custom summation function

Tags: evaluation, summation

I'm doing some computations that involve summations with many indices over the same range - consider the simplified example `Sum[a[i,j],{i,1,2},{j,1,2}]`. To prettify my code I'm attempting to define a helper function so I can write this as `S2[a[i,j],i,j]`. My first thought was pretty simple - just build the sequence of inputs to `Sum` and fire it off:

```
S2[expr_, indices__] :=  Sum @@ Join[{expr}, Map[{#, 1, 2} &, {indices}]];
```

This works for many inputs, but has some issues with premature evaluation that `Sum`,`Table`, etc. do not. Consider for example the input function `a[i_,j_]:=D[u[i],u[j]]`, which should produce the same outputs as `KroneckerDelta`. With our long-hand code we get the expected output:

```
In[1] := Sum[a[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]
Out[1] = 2
```

but with our S2 we do not:

```
In[2] := S2[a[i, j], i, j]
Out[2] = 0
```

This is due to `a` being evaluated before the values of `i` and `j` are assigned. I've tried setting `HoldFirst` on `S2`, replacing `expr` with `Hold[expr]` and releasing the hold at various places in the definition, but nothing I can think of gives me the desired behaviour.

What's the best way to accomplish what I want here (robust evaluation behaviour similar to that of `Sum`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following also works

```
SetAttributes[S3, HoldFirst];

S3[expr_, indices__] := 
 With[{ex = Unevaluated[expr]}, (Sum @@ 
    Join[{ex}, Map[{#, 1, 2} &, {indices}]])]
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
a[i_, j_] := D[u[i], u[j]]
ClearAll@S2
SetAttributes[S2, HoldFirst]
S2[expr_, indices__] := Sum @@ Join[Inactivate@{expr}, Map[{#, 1, 2} &, {indices}]] // Activate;
S2[b[i, j], i, j]
S2[a[i, j], i, j]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm stuck on Mathematica 9 at the moment - any way to do it without the new Activate/Inactivate?